# How to Add a discrete row to gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am binding the gridview and showing their corresponding total in footer without any error. Now I want to add extra runs as below highlighted in image(which is completely discrete datarow and it does not belong to dataset).I want to achieve functionality like below Image.

[image]

Here is my code :

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvFirstInningBatting" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
        GridLines="None" AllowPaging="false" CellPadding="4" CssClass="GridViewStyle" OnRowDataBound="gvFirstInningBatting_RowDataBound"
        ShowFooter="true" ShowHeader="true" Width="100%">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="P_PlayerPopulerName" HeaderText="Batting" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
                ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ItemStyle-Width="20%" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="SBTS_PlayerStatus" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
                ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ItemStyle-Width="20%" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="SBTS_RunsScored" HeaderText="R" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
                ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-Width="10%" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="SBTS_MinutesBatted" HeaderText="M" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
                ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-Width="10%" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="SBTS_BallsPlayed" HeaderText="B" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
                ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-Width="10%" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="SBTS_Fours" HeaderText="4s" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
                ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-Width="10%" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="SBTS_Sixes" HeaderText="6s" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
                ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-Width="10%" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="SBTS_StrikeRate" HeaderText="SR" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
                ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-Width="10%" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

In C#

```
protected void BindGridView(int scheduleId)
        {
            SqlConnection dBConnection = null;
            try
            {
                dBConnection = new SqlConnection();
                dBConnection.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["***"].ConnectionString;
                SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SP_NAME", dBConnection);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                dBConnection.Open();

                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                DataTable dtBatting = new DataTable();
                dataAdapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
                dataAdapter.Fill(ds);

                int gvBattingCount = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.Parameters["@BattingRowsCount"].Value);

                for (int i = 0; i < gvBattingCount; i++)
                {
                    if (ds.Tables[i].Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        if (i == 0)
                        {
                            DataRow dr1st;

                            ds.Tables[i].DefaultView.RowFilter = "SBTS_PlayerIsBatted = 1";
                            dtBatting = ds.Tables[i].DefaultView.ToTable();

                            dr1st = dtBatting.NewRow();
                            dr1st["P_PlayerPopulerName"] = " ";
                            dr1st["SBTS_RunsScored"] = 36;

                            dr1st["SBTS_PlayerStatus"] = "Extras";
                            dr1st["SBTS_MinutesBatted"] = 0;
                            dr1st["SBTS_BallsPlayed"] = 0;
                            dr1st["SBTS_Fours"] = 0;
                            dr1st["SBTS_Sixes"] = 0;
                            dr1st["SBTS_StrikeRate"] = 0;
                            dtBatting.Rows.Add(dr1st);

                            gvFirstInningBatting.DataSource = dtBatting;
                            gvFirstInningBatting.DataBind();
                        }
                    }
                }
           }
```

the grid is working if I use `dr1st["SBTS_Sixes"] = 0;` but it shows 0 in the row and if I use `dr1st["SBTS_Sixes"] = DBNull.Value;` then it is throwing error

> Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types.

What should I do, Please help me out.

Comment: It's tough to tell what the problem is.  At the end you say it works if you put zero.  If that's the case, why are you trying to use DBNull?

Comment: Actually I do not want to display 0 in the row. It should just display empty cell. That's why i am giving here DBNull.Value.

Comment: how about showing " "?

Comment: @AndréTrindadeFigueiredo I need to cast string to int. In this case it would show casting error.

Comment: What is the data type of SBTS_Sixes in the database?  Int?

Comment: Something is not right with your coding approach. Why do you need this columns as Int? If you really want to use int, you can't use DBNull.. try `null`. It makes no sense you try to go backwards and trying to save into DB the presented data. Save it into DB, cookie, Viewstate, etc..

Comment: Can you not just add a null int, so dr1st["SBTS_Sixes"] = (int?)null;